# C# BackgroundWorker not working as parameter

Tags: c#, loops, progress-bar, backgroundworker

```
public static void CalculateAttributions(BackgroundWorker worker, string _filename, ComboBox cmb, OpenFileDialog open)
        {
            worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
            while (wave.Position != length)
            {
               ...Process..
                worker.ReportProgress((100 * (int)(length / wave.Position)) / (int)(length / mainBuffer.Length));
            }
        }
```

I wrote this method in a class to perform my calculations and using `BackgroundWorker` as parameter to show a `Progressbar`during loop. However when i run this method in `Form.cs`

```
        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = Math.Min(e.ProgressPercentage, 100);
        }
```

this event is not working so `ProgressBar` value not changed. How can i make it work?

Comment: Why are you creating a *new* BackgroundWorker within the method? Are you calling BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync anywhere? Are you attaching the event handler to the worker anywhere? Basically, this doesn't look like a "normal" way of using BackgroundWorker at all...

Comment: Thank you for your first question. I have just created the new BackgroundWorker to set the WorkerReportsProgress = true. I should do it from backgroungWorker1's properties then it works. 
However i did not write BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync. I don't know where should i put it.

Comment: Well that's whatever *starts* the background worker...

Answer (score 0):

The report Progress event you have given here is for the backgroundworker1 and not the worker you coded within the function CalculateAttributions(...)

To enbale report progress and do progress bar changes.. Try the following code

`Worker1.ProgressChanged+=new delegate {
progressBar1.Value = Math.Min(e.ProgressPercentage, 100);
};`

with in the same function.

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to attach your event handlers. It should go like this.

```
public static void CalculateAttributions(BackgroundWorker worker, string _filename, ComboBox cmb, OpenFileDialog open)
        {
            worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
    worker.DoWork +=     new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
worker.ProgressChanged +=         new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

if (worker.IsBusy != true)
    {
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

}

 private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            while (wave.Position != length)
            {
               ...Process..
                worker.ReportProgress((100 * (int)(length / wave.Position)) / (int)(length / mainBuffer.Length));
            }
        }

private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = Math.Min(e.ProgressPercentage, 100);
        }

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //done
        }
```

Comment: I think I must move my method to `Form.cs` to perform these?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check this link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

The idea is to get your work inside background worker. and after each milestone report progress on your progress bar.

- create background worker object
- attach event handlers
- call RunWorkerAsynch()
- add code inside event handlers

  - do work will have the real work and report to progress call
  - report to progress will simply tell your progress bar to move one step ahead
  - completed will be called once everything is done. you may want to show a message to user that the operation is completed.

Comment: I think my problem is i don't now how do i call events from Form.cs while using class.